# Cost of reading from dataset

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I have a `DataSet` in my C# project, lets call it **MainDataSet**. In that DataSet, I have a table called **CustomerDataTable**. The datatable is filled with a table adapter, upon starting my program.

I also have a class called **CustomerClass.cs**, which maps pretty much 1:1 with the columns in the CustomerDataTable. Currently I have a method, `CustomerClass.Refresh()` which loads the various properties from the CustomerDataTable into the properties in CustomerClass, using LINQ. See an example below.

What I would like to know, is this: Would it be viable to link each property directly to the DataSet, instead of using a `.Refresh()` method? Currently that is okay, but my program and DataSet is still very tiny. I am worried about what will happen to the performance, when the program and DataSet grows.

**Refresh() Method**

```
CustomerDataTable cust = MainDataSet.Customer;
AddressDataTable addr = MainDataSet.Address;

var query = from customer in cust
            join address in addr on customer.id equals address.customerId
            where customer.id = this.customerId
            select new
            {
                customer.firstname,
                customer.lastname,
                address.streetname,
                address.streetnumber
            };

var result = query.Single();

this.FirstName = result.firstname;
this.LastName = result.lastname;
this.StreetName = result.streetname;
this.StreetNumber = result.streetnumber;
```

Comment: If it's a strongly typed DataSet you don't need the additional class, where do you store the instances at all, in a large `List<CustomerClass>`? Then you have already doubled the amount of memory needed. But why do you use the DataSet at all? You can load the data with `Ado.Net`, f.e. with a `SqlCommand` and a `SqlDataReader`. There you fill the `List<CustomerClass>`. You can also use a ORM like Linq-To-Entities or a tiny one like Dapper(which also stackoverflow uses). Then you have easy, maintainable code which is still efficient.

Comment: I am using a `DataSet`, because the company i work at does not allow us direct connection to an SQL database (yes, its quite hopeless, but not much I can do about it). So we want to load the data from one or more JSON files into the `DataSet`, hence getting some advantages of a DataBase, without having one.

Comment: Memory footprint for your CustomerClass would be small and I wouldnt worry about that. If ther's anything you should worry about it's the memory footprint of data set. That being said, you could potentialy pass DataRow object to the constructor of Customer and design the class in such a way that accesing each property would go into that instance of row and fetch the value from the column.

Comment: I ended up changing my code, so that there is a LINQ query in each property. This seems to work reasonably well at the moment.

Comment: What database advantages do you think you are getting from `DataSet`? With some `List`s over the plain classes and LINQ to Objects, you can get all the query advantages with none of the `DataSet` overhead.

Comment: @NetMage to be honest, I have no way near enough experience, to answer that question. We mainly did it, because it resembled something familiar (databases). You might be right, maybe there is no reason at all to use dataset. Maybe a static (or single instance) class with lists, would be better. I will keep your idea in mind, thank you.